# Full text search, contains and correlated query

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains

1. The rules table stores complex terms for FTS (e.g. '"*endwith" and "startwith*" or (...)')
2. The documents table stores contents of user's documents
3. Create a view to display all matches between `rules.keywordTerms` and `documents.documentTexts`

My attempt:

```
create view vuRulesMatchedToDocumentTexts
as
    select 
        r.keywordTerms, d.documentTexts
    from
        rules r
    cross apply 
        (select documentID, documentTexts 
         from documents 
         where contains(documentTexts, r.keywordTerms)) d
go
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
> Incorrect syntax near 'r'.

Comment: The second parameter of `CONTAINS` expects a scalar value/variable, not a column.

Comment: how to workaround with performance concerns

Comment: What performance concern are you referencing here?

Comment: I think what @ThomA is trying to say is that you can't use Contains function with columns, so your view is impossible to create. I guess you can spell out the rules by using CONTAINS(document, 'SOME RULE STRING') OR CONTAINS(document, 'SECOND RULE STRING') etc

Comment: i have tens thousands of rules + hundred thousands of documents to match, all i can do these days are using a cursor to get each rule's keywordTerms and passing it to a stored to get matched items ... but this is killing me